# DNS seems broken after iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source SERVERIP -o eth+

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04

During the setup of a L2PD VPN in Ubuntu 14.04, this line is entered

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source *PUBLIC_IP* -o eth+

and then all the domains cannot be resolved in this server.

I admit I don't know anything about iptables. The VPN works fine, but shadowsocks doesn't work anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: DNS is broken from where to where? can you provide more details?

Comment: After the line above entered in the server, ping hostname doesn't work anymore and apt-get update fails.

Comment: long time ago, did you find the cause? Same scenario here.